# How do I make an HTTP POST call to the Shopify API from in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, post, aws-lambda, shopify

I've tried making POST requests with

```
var https = require('https');
```

and

```
var request = require('request');
```

I have the request package in the node_modules folder in the Lambda function. Neither of them seem to be able to properly authenticate with Shopify and send the request properly. What is the best way to go about this? I can't seem to find an example anywhere. This is not a webhook, I'm not getting data, I'm trying to update a metafield on a customer when something else triggers this Lambda function.

Comment: Share the code that you are using to send the POST request.

Comment: post your code first, but I'm guessing you're not using `await` to actually wait for the response. If so, the lambda function will terminate before the result is actually retrieved (if there is not a lot of following code which keep it running)

Comment: turns out when the function is set to async as in "exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>" then it does not work and you need to remove "async" and then it works properly